# How to get frame rate from a HTML video player

Tags: video, html5-video, frame-rate

HTML video player must know the frame rate of the file its playing, otherwise it could inevitably play back a video at the wrong speed.

How can I get the frame rate that the video player is currently using for the currently loaded video?

Comment: “otherwise [sic] play back video at the wrong speed”. This is false. Every frame is individually time stamped, and the player can play back variable frame rate files.

Comment: Is there a way to get the value of this time stamp?

Comment: No, not without parsing the binary data directly. You can only get the `currentTime` in javascript.

Comment: currentTime wont help me.  Im looking for a frame rate value.  Why would a video player parse important information like frame rate, but not include a way to use that info outside of the video player.  Framerate is one of the three most important video stats.  Height and Width are the other two most important stats.

Comment: `Framerate is one of the three most important video stats` In the broadcast industry, yes, but there you have genlock. In streaming/internet media you MUST assume variable framerate and you can have a VERY high variance. If I have 2 seconds of video, and the first second has 59 frames, and the second second has 1 frame, what is my frame rate? 59? 30? or 1? All are correct, and all are wrong. There is no such thing as instantaneous frame rate on the internet.

Comment: Genlock is a sync pulse that you can time video equipment to.  You set genlock to the know frame rate value of the entire system.  Not sure why we diverged into Genlock, its not related to my question so lets get back on track.   Lets assume I never work with variable frame rate.  How can I get the frame rate of the video?  The video player knows the frame rate (variable or not), why cant I query the video player and learn what it knows (even though in the case of a variable frame rate the variable may change from one second to the next).

Comment: "Lets assume I never work with variable frame rate" The player can never assume that. It MUST assume all videos are variable frame rate, because it can not tell the future. It could be constant rite now, But there may be a big gap in frames coming up it hasn't encountered yet. And there is nothing in the media format that can guaranteed a constant frame rate. Since the player MUST assume variable, it has no need to understand constant, so it doesn't bother.

Answer (score 0):

you can test each video you are looking at with FFprobe.  Its part of FFMPEG, and I've built an online version at https://ffprobe.a.video.

It'll tell you the bitrate (and a host of other interesting facts about your video

It requires a Node Server, and FFMPEG:

the URL is sent as a query string, and then popped into ffprobe.... the rest of the Node is formatting...

```
app.get('/probe', (req,res) =>{
    let url = req.query.url;
    console.log(" url="+url);
  let ffprobeResult = ffprobe(url) 
  
  ffprobeResult.then(function(info){
    
    //extract some essentials
    //sometimes video is thr first stream.. someties second
    var streamCount = info.format.nb_streams;
   

    //format data is overall
    var bitrate= info.format.bit_rate;
    var sizeBytes = info.format.size;
    var duration = info.format.duration;
    var formatName = info.format.format_name;
    var formatLong = info.format.format_long_name;

    //get video/audio specific infos
    for (var i=0;i<streamCount;i++){
      if (info.streams[i].codec_type == "video"){

        var height = info.streams[i].height;
        var width =info.streams[i].width;
        var aspectRatio = info.streams[i].display_aspect_ratio;
        var videoCodec = info.streams[i].codec_name;
      }else{
        //audio
        var audioCodec = info.streams[i].codec_name;
      }

    }


    console.log(bitrate, sizeBytes, duration, formatLong);
    console.log(height, width, aspectRatio, videoCodec, audioCodec);
    var format = info.format;
    var streams = info.streams;
    console.log(format);
    console.log(streams);

    return res.render('results', {format, streams, bitrate, sizeBytes, duration, formatLong, height, width, aspectRatio, videoCodec,audioCodec});
```

But this data is not exposed from the HTML5 video player.

Doug

Comment: Hi Doug.  Your solution is interesting.  I wish you had it bundled into a nice js file with HTML code samples on how to use the js.  Without the .js and HTML examples, Im afraid I dont have the stomach for the learning curve adventure required to attempt your solution.

Answer (score -2):

If you want the frame rate please follow the below solution.

```
   $(video).on('timeupdate', function () {
    var ct = document.getElementById('#video').currentTime;
    var dur = document.getElementById('#video').duration;
    var videoProgressPos = ct / dur;         
    console.log(videoProgressPos)
 });
```

This videoProgressPos variable will give you the current frame of your video that you playing.
I mixed JS and jQuery, you can develop it as your wish logic.
If my answer did not help you, please let me know.
Thank you.

Comment: returns a value of 0.022709619483203294  Not sure what this number means exactly.  I expected a typical frame rate value such as 60 or 59.94 or 30 or 29.97 or 24

Comment: Unfortunately **this doesn't calculate FPS**: It returns a relative timestamp (e.g. 0.5 if you are at half the video). You have to divide the number of frames by the duration to get an (average) framerate ... but this doesn't seem to be exposed by JS.